# Vuejs require("axios") in .js file, require is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, axios, get

I'm using vuejs and I'm trying to make a GET request to my API. I'm using axios, but I cannot import it, if I use `require` to import axios i get this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`.

This is my vuetest.js file:

```
const axios = require("axios");

new Vue({
  el: "#rentalsVue",
  data() {
    return {
      info: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get("/getRentals").then((response) => (this.info = response));
  },
});
```

This is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="rentalsVue">
        {{ info }}
    </div>


    <script src="vuetest.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `require()` doesn't exist on browser/client-side JavaScript.

You need to import Axios using the `<script>` tag and then you will be able to use it.